# I want to remain on same page after i report a comment

Tags: php, mysql

so i want to make a little blog in php and mysql using a mvc arhitecture.i want to add a function where you can report a comment(everything went well but i can't figure out how to remain on the same page after reporting)

for showing the page with the post and the comments for that post i'm using 2 functions

```
public function getPost($postId)
{
    $db = $this->dbConnect();
    $req = $db->prepare('SELECT id, title, content, DATE_FORMAT(creation_date, \'%d/%m/%Y à %Hh%imin%ss\') AS creation_date_fr FROM posts WHERE id = ?');
    $req->execute(array($postId));
    $post = $req->fetch();
    return $post;
}

public function getComments($postId)
{
    $db = $this->dbConnect();
    $comments = $db->prepare('SELECT id, author, comment,report_status, DATE_FORMAT(comment_date, \'%d/%m/%Y à %Hh%imin%ss\') AS comment_date_fr FROM comments WHERE post_id = ? ORDER BY comment_date DESC');
    $comments->execute(array($postId));
    return $comments;
}
```

and this is my controller :

```
function post(){
    $postManager = new PostManager();
    $commentManager = new CommentManager();

    $post = $postManager->getPost($_GET['id']);
    $comments = $commentManager->getComments($_GET['id']);

    require('view/frontend/postView.php');
    }
```

my function for reporting the comment is this

```
public function reportComment($id)
{
    $db = $this->dbConnect();
    $report = $db->prepare('UPDATE comments SET report_status = 1 WHERE id = :id');
    $report->bindParam(':id', $id, PDO::PARAM_INT);
    $report->execute();
}
```

and the controller

```
function report(){
    $commentManager = new CommentManager();
    $commentManager->reportComment($_GET['id']);
```

}

my problem is that i can't redirect the user to the page of post(id) because i already set the new $_GET to the comment id,not the post id; how can i store the old post id so i can stay on the same page...

here is my index.php so you get a full picture

```
elseif ($_GET['action'] == 'post') {
    if (isset($_GET['id']) && $_GET['id'] > 0) {
        post();
    }...

elseif($_GET['action'] == 'report'){


    if(!empty($_GET['id'])&& $_GET['id'] > 0){
        report();

    }
    else{
        echo 'not reported';
    }
```

Comment: You could always do this as an Ajax call, then it won't ever leave or reload the page.

Comment: unfortunately i'm still trying yo understand Ajax calls.. i will give it a try. ty

Comment: Are these variables being accessed via the query string? for example: `mysite.com/index.php?action=report&id=1` and if so are those the only 2 parameters used?

Comment: @FoxyFish yes the variable is accessed  via query string. first i get the id of the blog post..i use 2 function(first to show the post and the second to show the comments for that post) and then i use another to change the report status of a particular comment(by id).when i use that i lose the id of the post and i can't redirect on the same page

Comment: In that case the simplest way to solve your problem is to use separate variables for post id and comment id in the query string, then no matter what you do you will still have access to them both. Report using the comment id and redirect using the post id.

Comment: Or if it can't be in the query string, at whatever point id changes from the post id to the comment id  have it create a new variable called commentid and pass that to the report function  instead of overwriting it and losing it, then id will remain as your post id to redirect with.

Answer (score 0):

why you don't add more param to $_GET (ex: $_GET('post_id'))

and fix little in this code:

```
 if(!empty($_GET['id'])&& $_GET['id'] > 0){
        report();
    $postId = $_GET('post_id');
    ///// redirect to post by $postId

 }
```

Comment: i tried... it tries to redirect me to the post with the id of the comment.. not the post itself.